# Append additional text to panel

Tags: extjs

I'm dnymically loading text from responses on one panel and i'm having problem of proper formatting or appending the text.

For example this `this.messagePanel.body.dom.innerHTML` returns:

```
"<div id="panel-1428-outerCt" data-ref="outerCt" class="x-autocontainer-outerCt" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%;">
    <div id="panel-1428-innerCt" data-ref="innerCt" style="padding:5px 5px 5px 5px" class="x-autocontainer-innerCt">
       My Text...
    </div>
</div>"
```

Now i wan't to append additional text for example TEST, so the final result should look like this

```
"<div id="panel-1428-outerCt" data-ref="outerCt" class="x-autocontainer-outerCt" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%;">
        <div id="panel-1428-innerCt" data-ref="innerCt" style="padding:5px 5px 5px 5px" class="x-autocontainer-innerCt">
           My Text...
           <br>
           TEST
         </div>
    </div>"
```

So far i was doing this with this code, which is totally wrong and now i'm trying to find a proper solution

```
var oldMessage = this.messagePanel.body.dom.innerText;
var newMessage = oldMessage + "<br><br>" + message + "<br><br>";
var html =
    "<div id='panel-1459-outerCt' data-ref='outerCt' class='x-autocontainer-outerCt' role='presentation'" +
    " style='width:100%; table-layout:fixed; height:100%;'>" +
    "<div id='panel-1459-innerCt' data-ref='innerCt' style='padding:5px 5px 5px 5px' class='x-autocontainer-innerCt'>" +
    newMessage +
    "</div></div>";
this.messagePanel.body.update(html);
```

Can you please help me find a way to add text in new line on panel, which is already holding some text. I'm using EXTJS 6. If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can do the trick!

Here is the working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kvu

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var win=Ext.create({
            xtype:'window',
            width:200,
            height:300,
            html:'text...'
        });
        win.html+='<br>TEST</br>';
        win.show();
    }
});
```

Other way is to use a simple label, and add it to the panel

```
var label=Ext.create({
xtype:'label',
html:'<br>TEST</br>'
});
panel.add(label);
```

Or simply hiding labels or component created before.

Comment: Yes its true, but did you know something about addHtml and not setHtml(getHtml+)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I don't find an `addHtml` function in the docs, not even in the ExtJS source.

Comment: Sorry , bad english, i mean that in my opinion if you have to add a value you should only add it and not getting the old one, adding to the old one the new value to append and then write over the variable. Just a personal feeling.

Comment: it should be a great question to discuss

Comment: It's a question you can ask Sencha. For the time being, you can of course add an override to your ExtJS project with an `addHtml` function made from the snippets above. Please keep in mind that the underlying strings are immutable in javascript as per the language specifications, and that such helper functions are not available in fiddle.